# Two DataFrames, find index of second one where values of two columns match up from first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have two pandas DataFrames as pictured.

DF1:

```
              0     1     2     3    4
0    2021-02-24  19.0  35.0  34.5  0.0
1    2021-02-24  20.0  33.0  34.5  0.0
2    2021-02-24  21.0  30.0  34.5  0.0
3    2021-02-24  22.0  28.0  34.5  0.0
4    2021-02-24  23.0  27.0  34.5  0.0
..          ...   ...   ...   ...  ...
163  2021-03-03  14.0  43.0  25.0  0.0
164  2021-03-03  15.0  47.0  25.0  0.0
165  2021-03-03  16.0  50.0  25.0  0.0
166  2021-03-03  17.0  51.0  25.0  0.0
167  2021-03-03  18.0  51.0  25.0  0.0

[168 rows x 5 columns]
```

DF2 (192 x 7):

```
              0    1     2     3     4     5    6
3171 2021-02-24  3.0   1.0   1.0  29.0  37.0  0.0
3172 2021-02-24  3.0   2.0   2.0  28.0  37.0  0.0
3173 2021-02-24  3.0   3.0   3.0  26.0  37.0  0.0
3174 2021-02-24  3.0   4.0   4.0  25.0  37.0  0.0
3175 2021-02-24  3.0   5.0   5.0  25.0  37.0  0.0
3176 2021-02-24  3.0   6.0   6.0  24.0  37.0  0.0
3177 2021-02-24  3.0   7.0   7.0  22.0  37.0  0.0
3178 2021-02-24  3.0   8.0   8.0  21.0  37.0  0.0
3179 2021-02-24  3.0   9.0   9.0  21.0  37.0  0.0
3180 2021-02-24  3.0  10.0  10.0  22.0  37.0  0.0
3181 2021-02-24  3.0  11.0  11.0  23.0  37.0  0.0
3182 2021-02-24  3.0  12.0  12.0  26.0  37.0  0.0
3183 2021-02-24  3.0  13.0  13.0  29.0  37.0  0.0
3184 2021-02-24  3.0  14.0  14.0  32.0  37.0  0.0
3185 2021-02-24  3.0  15.0  15.0  33.0  37.0  0.0
3186 2021-02-24  3.0  16.0  16.0  35.0  37.0  0.0
3187 2021-02-24  3.0  17.0  17.0  35.0  37.0  0.0
3188 2021-02-24  3.0  18.0  18.0  34.0  37.0  0.0
3189 2021-02-24  3.0  19.0  19.0  33.0  37.0  0.0
3190 2021-02-24  3.0  20.0  20.0  31.0  37.0  0.0
```

I want to find the index value of DF2 where `df1[0] & df1[1]` match `df2[0] & df2[2]`. For more detail, this would be represented above as starting at index `3188` of DF2. DF1 values will be dynamically changing as DF2 stays constant.

Edit: Just noticed that there was an error in my logic. I meant `DF1[0] == DF2[0]` and `DF1[1]==DF2[2]`. I have updated above accordingly.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k). Please [read this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as to why it is discouraged.

Comment: Use `print(df)` in notebook, and copy paste it as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, updated.

Comment: `&` is a Boolean operator, and the columns aren't Booleans. I believe that in Python,  `&` on integers is interpreted as bitwise logical AND, which is likely not what you want. You probably mean `(df1[0] == df2[0]) & (df1[1] == df2[1])`, which is quite different. (Bitwise logical AND means Python takes the binary representation of the numbers, then applies AND pairwise to the binary digits of the numbers.)

Comment: When Pandas compares two dataframes, it matches up the indexes. Your dataframes seem to have different indexes, which means that it's ambiguous as to what should be compared to what. What you *seem* to be asking is "How do I find the offset which, when applied to the index, will result in the dataframes being the same", but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: If this is any clearer, I want to find the row where the values start to match up for two columns, in this case  ```DF1[0] == DF2[0] and DF1[1]==DF2[2]```. Which would be index ```3188``` of DF2. Ideally I want to copy DF1 to replace all rows ```>= 3188``` on DF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the first place where `DF2` matches `DF1` with `offset = DF2.loc[ (DF2[0] == DF1.loc[0,0]) & (DF2[1] == DF1.loc[0,1])] ][0]`. If you want to then test whether the rest of the columns match up, you'll have to get them to have the same shape and the same index. In this case, the part of DF2 after the matching row is smaller than DF1 overall, so one way to do this is as follows (if DF1 were smaller, the process would be a bit different):

```
 DF2_tail = DF2.loc[offset:].copy()
 num_rows = DF2_tail.shape[0]
 DF2_tail.index = range(num_rows)
 DF1.loc[:num_rows,[0,1]].eq(DF2_tail[[0,1]])
```